# I am getting an error when trying to make API calls to Forge BIM360 API?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to make endpoint calls to the forge BIM360 API but I keep getting the following error message:
"{ ""developerMessage"":""The client_id specified does not have access to the api product"", ""moreInfo"": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/", ""errorCode"": ""AUTH-001""}"

I have setup the custom integration correctly and I have successfully received an access code.

I am using RESTSHARP and vb.net for my calls.
Here is my code:

```
Dim client3 = New RestClient(https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/<my account ID 
with a b. in beginning>/projects)
Dim request3 = New RestRequest(Method.GET)
request3.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & strAccessToken)
Dim response3 As IRestResponse = client3.Execute(request3)
strJSON = response3.Content
```

Has anyone had this issue before and are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API authorization is needed for your ClientID from your custom integrations tab in the Admin portal. Follow the steps listed here: https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/bim-360-activating-api-access-to-docs/

Comment: Great to hear, It can help others if you mark this as the answer to your questions. Cheers.